# If a box is at rest on an inclined plane, as you increase $\theta$, $F_n$ decreases but $F_f$ increases?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, friction, free-body-diagram

If $F_f =\mu× F_n$, then why does $F_f$ increase when $F_n$ decreases?
*[Here $F_f$ is frictional force, $F_n$ is normal force and $\mu$ is coefficient of friction]*

Answer (score 2):

You are probably thinking the static friction force, $F_f$, acting up the incline always equals $\mu_{s}F_n$. It doesn't.

Static friction $F_f$ is a variable force that equals the force acting on the object down the plane, $mg\sin\theta$, up until the static friction force equals the maximum possible static friction force, or $F_{f}=\mu_{s}F_n$, is reached at which point sliding is impending.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Because the box remains at rest. (I know that's a ball but pretend is a box).

The normal force (F<sub>n</sub>) and the force of friction (F<sub>f</sub>) must balance for the box to remain at rest. That's why F<sub>f</sub> increases as F<sub>n</sub> decreases.

So in that context what does this mean?

F<sub>f</sub> = µ F<sub>n</sub>

This tells you the max F<sub>f</sub> that friction can provide to keep the box from sliding.

[image]

To make sense of that think about 0<sup>o</sup>. Here's a box on a surface that has a 0<sup>o</sup> incline (commonly known as the floor). Does F<sub>f</sub> = µ F<sub>n</sub> mean the box is going to just suddenly slide sideways?

[image]

No. It means that's how hard you'd have to push it to make it slide sideways. Don't push hard enough and it wont slide. This is why they call friction a reactionary force. You only get the max F<sub>f</sub> when something is opposing it the same amount. Push harder than that and sliding starts happening (and you start using the sliding coefficient of friction which is typically a little different coefficient).

This is why you don't know if Figure A or B is moving. Without knowing the coefficient of friction you don't know if 5 lb or 100 lb is enough to get the box to slide.

[image]

Here's a diagram that labels all the forces we're talking about. But it's still a bit confusing because F<sub>f</sub> has two magnitudes: the max that can oppose F<sub>∥</sub> before sliding happens and the amount reacting to the current magnitude of F<sub>∥</sub>.

Those two different magnitudes are why you have two different ways of calculating F<sub>f</sub>. Here they are:

Max before sliding:
F<sub>f</sub> = µ F<sub>n</sub>

Reaction force that can't exceed max:
F<sub>f</sub> = - F<sub>∥</sub>